# How to pseudorandom ORDER BY records in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm thinking about ORDER BY condition in MySQL which would pseudo random ordered records each day different. That means that it would include today's date in formula. And result would be random orderdered records which would change every day.

I hope that you understand my explenation, feel free to ask.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: you mean like `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: so they need to change everyday but not between runs on the same day right? so ORDER BY RAND() won't work since everytime run will change

Comment: not sure, but i think this could work (in postgres it does..)
`ORDER By (SELECT however you generate a value for this day)`

Comment: Make a column RowNumber which will be a random number and a nightly job that updates it... which you would then ORDER BY.  Search for MySQL No Repetition Combinations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ORDER BY DAYOFMONTH(NOW())` maybe?

Each day it will order your results in different way.

`ORDER BY RAND()` will order your results differently every run of the query

Comment: won't be random... the order will be the same with respect to the data even though the day changes.

Comment: Can't use `ORDER BY RAND()`
I need smth like `LIMIT DAYOFMONTH(NOW()*5),12`, that means its not totally random but its same all day long. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Try ORDER BY DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) as I said. ORDER BY RAND is not good solution for your needs

Comment: problem is DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) is the same for every row

Comment: Hmm I found out that it orders every day the same. So its not working

Answer (score 1):

Order by

```
(id of the row times) ^ the day number     mod      n
```

where n is close to the expected number of results... This will change everyday, appear pseudo random, and will not change between runs on the same day.  You should be careful how you choose n though so that a lot of the numbers don't come out the same (try to make it prime)